# is there any more parameters that i must add to AJAX function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using `$.ajax` to insert data into database. But no data will be inserted and I don't receive any data in `success` function. Do I have to set more parameters into the `success` function?

#### That's what I currently have:

JS:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/pro.php',
    data: {
        'name':name,
        'email':email,
        'reply':reply    
    },
    type: 'post',       
    success: function() {

    }
});
```

PHP:

```php
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 
$dbuser = 'root'; 
$dbpass = ''; 
$dbname = 'redskydb'; 
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','yasi','ucsc','redskydb'); 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$reply = $_POST['reply']; 
$query="INSERT INTO feedbacks (CusId,Reply,Name)VALUES('$email','$reply','$name')";
```

Comment: <?php

 $dbhost = 'localhost';
 $dbuser = 'root';
 $dbpass = '';
 $dbname = 'redskydb';

 $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','yasi','ucsc','redskydb');



   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $reply = $_POST['reply'];
   


   $query="INSERT INTO feedbacks (CusId,Reply,Name)VALUES('$email','$reply','$name')";

?>

Comment: Welcome, fyi, you can _edit_ your question and paste relevant data there instead of the comments

Comment: Remove the quotes from your `data`

Comment: it seems correct. is there any error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `ajax`. Don't put the `object` keys in quotes and pass the `success` function the `result` parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: './pro.php',
    data: {
      name: 'nameValue',
      email: 'emailValue',
      reply: 'replyValue',

    },
    type: 'POST',       
    success: function(result) {
        console.log('this is result from call', result);
    }
});
```

### UPDATE

Please check your `pro.php` first it is not save an on the other hand, your `Values(...)` are set incorrectly. My code is just an example, how you could going through.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "redskydb");
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
    exit('Error connecting to database');
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO feedbacks (CusId, Reply, Name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($_POST['email'], $_POST['reply'], $_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();

//here you could select with last_id and fetch the inserted row, but don't return before close()

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: still its not working i just put a alert inside success: function but its not appearing thanks for the help guys. I am a mobile application developer web application is new to me.

Comment: @YasithaHerath see my updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help I had made many mistakes finally i did it calling the js function in html onclick didnt work for me had to do it using a listener document.getElementById("sendr").addEventListener("click", SubmitReply, false);document.getElementById("sendr").addEventListener("click", SubmitReply, false);

Comment: Thanks, you really must to take care of incoming data and sql injection.